# Is it possible to rename a Database and have existing assets connect to it?

Tags: azure-sql-database

We have to rebuild a database that has Azure sql server ledgering switched on in favour of one that doesn't.  This may be over simplistic, but is it possible to rename the new database to the name of the old one and have assets with existing connections work?

The process would look something like this:

DB01-Ledger
DB02-Non Ledger

Rename DB01 to DB01_OLD
Rename DB02 to DB01

Would things like Power BI reports or Power Automate Flows that connected to the original DB01 just connect to the new DB01 or would they need re connecting?

Currently we have built a new database but I don't want to rename the original DB if there is no point!

Comment: If credentials and other thigs like logins/users are same then it may redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the database security aspects are same (users,logins and their access) and the database is on the same server, there wont be any issue as all the jobs would repoint to it.

Usually that's how we do backups in case of synapse and some other databases wherein we 1st restore the backup as a new database.
Rename the original one to something else and rename the restored one as the original database name.